# how to get files uploaded from file zilla in elastic beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have My web services coded in php and its hosted on aws using elastic bean stalk .If I want to edit any of my code I am connecting to the EC@ instance from file zilla and connecting to the server.Sincek is in autoscaling what it does is it automatically scales up and down depending upon the traffic and data storage so when it scales down It takes the copy of the latest zip file uploaded from the aws dashbord and replace that with the current system configuration , it does not take back up of files uploaded from file zilla.So is there any way where in I can get back my previously uploded files to the server from file zilla?

I even tried connecting to the EC2 instance using ssh but I could not find my previous files over there also . Is it this that correct way to upload any application is from elastic beanstalk dashbord only ? and not editing from file zilla?

Answer (score 1):

You are right that it will pick up the version of the file originally deployed when the instances scale up or down.
The recommended workflow for this scenario are to upload the zip file to the AWS console using the "Upload and Deploy" button.

You can also use CLI tools or APIs like:

awscli: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/index.html

eb http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-eb.html

UpdateEnvironment API: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateEnvironment.html

Given that your current workflow involves the console, you can upload a new version of the file using the AWS console.

Read the walkthrough here for more details:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/GettingStarted.Walkthrough.html

Comment: I agree that deploying new application versions is the correct way of making updates in Elastic Beanstalk. I would add that this is the also the best of way to preserving previous versions, which were lost when EB autoscaled after his direct edits on the server.